# Java programming language class and package

Tags: java

what is the default package and default class in java?

i checked on the internet but couldn't find a concrete answer. So please reply for my question.

Comment: are u sure that u r asking a question and not ordering us.;)

Comment: default package will be your `src`.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as "default class".  "Default package" is another word for the "unnamed package" described in the [Java Language Specification section 7.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t explicitly package your classes or interfaces, In that case, they’re
packaged in a *default, no-name* package. This default package is automatically imported in
the Java classes and interfaces defined within the same directory on your system. 
A class from a default package can’t be used in any named packaged class, regardless
of whether they are defined within the same directory or not.